# How to Check if any of top 2 processes is oracle instance process using shell script?

Tags: oracle, shell

I need to check top 2 process is the oracle instance process is running If “Yes” send mail with v$session details from database and sql text for the query..

I have tried the below code:

```
  cpu_ps=`top -b -o +%MEM | head -n 10 | grep ora* | head -n 2 | awk '{print $12}' | sed -e 's/ora_mman_*//g'`
ora_cpu=`echo -e "${cpu_ps} \n"`
    for ORACLE_SID in $ora_cpu
    do
        export ORACLE_SID=${ORACLE_SID}
        echo $ORACLE_SID
        export ORACLE_HOME=`grep -i "^${ORACLE_SID}:" /etc/oratab | cut -d: -f2 -s`
        export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
         cpu_report=`${ORACLE_HOME}/bin/sqlplus -S -M "HTML ON TABLE 'BORDER="2"'" / as sysdba <<-EOF
        SET PAGES 10000
        SET LINES 3000
        COLUMN username  FOR a20
        COLUMN machine FOR a100
        select username,machine,program,status,count(*) from gv\\$session group by username,machine,program,status order by 1 asc;
exit
EOF`
echo $cpu_report > oracle_cpu_process.html
```

done

I got the output like this

```
       **ora_mman_or+
       ora_mman_au+**
```

Actually my oracle instance is orcle and autodb but it displaying like above output...

How need to check whether top 2 process is oracle instance ? and need to check for every 2 minutes

Comment: You tried that code... so what happened? What is wrong with it? You haven't said what problem you are having.

Comment: If you want to distinguish between user sessions and Oracle background sessions you can use v$session.type. Possiblae values are USER, BACKGROUND, RECURSIVE.